# Reading JSON from online - best method

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a JSON file from within my GitHub repository but I keep getting an SSL certificate error. The code below has been simplified greatly as it is reading a JSON as part of a larger function that uses the data in a port scan but just looking for a quick fix.

`test1.json` (sample):

```
{
    "7": "Echo",
    "19": "Chargen",
    "20": "FTP",
    "21": "FTP",
    "22": "SSH/SCP",
    "23": "Telnet",
    "25": "SMTP",
    "42": "WINS Replication",
    "43": "WHOIS",
    "49": "TACACS",
}
```

Any idea on the best way to do this?

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://github.com/UNAME/REPO/blob/master/test1.json"
ports_and_services_file = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(ports_and_services_file.read())
print(data)

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link to json file is not correct. Follow these steps to get a correct link.

##### Step 1: Open target file on github and click on `RAW` button

[image]

##### Step 2: Copy the url from browser url field

The url domain should be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...`

[image]

---

After that you can read the file from url and convert to pandas dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gremur/stackoverflow/main/71409474_data.json"

df = pd.read_json(url)

df
```

Returns

[image]